# more table or more rows better in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Actually i am building a software for academic institutions, so i just wanted to know answers of a few questions:

As you know the some new data will be generated each year(for new admissions) and some will be upgraded. So i should store all the data in one single table with academic year separation(as a columns like ac_year), or should i make separate tables for each year. Also that there are different tables to store information like, classes,marks,fee,hostel,etc  about the students. So each Info, like Fee would be stored in different tables like 
Fee-2010
Fee-2011
Fee-2012...

Or in 1 single Fee table with year as a columns.

One more point is that soon after 1-2 years database will get heavier so backing up data for a single year would be possible in single table(Like Fee with year as a column) ?

And
Please answer keeping in mind SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate more. You need to show what efforts have you made. Please edit your question otherwise i am afraid that no one will be able to help you

Comment: Please just add the column `ac_year` on all those tables. One different version of your table per year is a maintenance nightmare, and also will hugely complicate querying your data afterwards

Comment: yup but one more thing is that, if i store all the info in a single table, then after some years the database will get heavy. So how would i backup only 1 year's data from the table. And also can i later on separate(backup and delete) data from the table.

Comment: If you're ever interested in the "how" at a deeper level, google "ER diagram relational mapping".  Here is a video about it.   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIkw87aLAMc

Answer (score 2):

As you phrase the question, the answer is clearly to store the data in one table, with the year (or date or other information) as a column.  This is simply the right thing to do.  You are dealing with the same entity over time.

The one exception would be when the fields are changing significantly from one year to the next.  I doubt that is the case for your table.

If your database is really getting big, then you can look into partitioning the table by time.  Each partition would be one year's worth of data.  This would speed up queries that only need to access one year's worth.  It also helps with backing up and restoring data.  This may be the solution you are ultimately looking for.

"Really getting big" means at least millions of rows in the table.  Even with a couple million rows in the table, most queries will probably run fine on decent hardware with appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not typical to store the data in multiple tables based on time constraints.  I would prefer to store it all in one table.  In the future, you may look to archiving old data, but it will still be significant time before performance will become an issue.

Comment: Typically if you do see a need to break down the results by time you create a partitioned table (although true partitioning is only available with Enterprise in SQL 2005).  Partitioning can dramatically improve performance, but isn't really needed unless you have a large number of rows to deal with.  For school admissions it probably isn't needed (unless you are perhaps doing admissions for every school in Texas at once).

Comment: :) yup but actually i would be storing images of the students in the database so that it may be available for other network clients.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better option to add new property to entity than create a new entity for every different property. This way maintenance and querying will be much more easier for you. 
On the performance part of querying you don't have to worry about internal affairs of data and database. If there become a real performance issue there are many solutions like Creating Index on years as in your situation.